# implicit conversions and polymorphism

Tags: c++

pretty straight-forward question, I am attempting to get an implicit conversion working with a polymorphic parameter, is there any way to get this working?

main.cpp

```
nickname nick("somenick");
client.send(nick_request(nick)); // original
client.send(nick); // Implicit conversion from nickname to nick_request
```

client.hpp

```
virtual void send(const request & rq)
```

nick_request.hpp

```
class nick_request : public request
{
    nick_request(const nickname & nick);
    ...
};
```

nickname.hpp

```
nickname(const std::string & name)
```

One solution would be to write out an overload for each type of "request", but that's tedious and defeats the point of the polymorphism.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might write a conversion function (from `nickname` to `nick_request`) in `nickname`.

```
class nickname {
public:
    nickname(const std::string & name) {}
    operator nick_request() const { return nick_request(*this); }
};
```

[LIVE](http://rextester.com/ZQR54501)

See [user-defined conversion](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cast_operator)

Comment: That is fantastic, I had no idea this could be done!

Comment: @FranciscoAguilera It makes the compiler could find the conversion route.

Comment: can you explain how this would work with multiple parameters? For example if nick_request took multiple parameters?

Comment: @FranciscoAguilera Like this `return nick_request(*this, xxx, yyy, zzz);`?

Comment: Correct, where xxx, yyy, zzz are other classes similar to nickname (username, usermodes)...

Comment: @FranciscoAguilera Does class `nickname` hold these info? If not, you might not use implicit casting. Just construct nick_request explicitly. As your code showed, `client.send(nick_request(nickname, username, usermodes));`